# Is the beginning of Max Richter's "On the Nature of Daylight" recorded by 3 cellos, or 2 cellos and 1 viola?

Tags: audio-recording, instruments

It seems to sound like 3 cellos

but I'm not sure.

However, in another recording it sounds very similar but it shows a non-cello playing one of the 3 beginning voices:

(however, it is worth noting that the video footage doesn't even match the sounds being played for this recording, especially in terms of vibrato)

Maybe it's 3 cellos in the first version and 2 cellos 1 viola in the 2nd version?

Answer (score 1):

In the first video that's definitely a viola playing the melody line.

The video in the second is way out of synch with the audio - not a great production there. Sound is better in the first video.

Comment: Thanks! Just to make sure, by "melody line" you mean the very beginning with 3 voices, not the violin that comes in at 1:42 right?

Comment: The work is scored for two violins, viola and two 'celli.